# js client connecct to go-socket.io server, but get repeated reconnection

Tags: go, socket.io

I'm tring to implement some websocket service, since I'm using gin as web framework, so I choose `go-socket.io`. I run `go-socket.io`'s cors example. Server code as below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

    socketio "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io"
)

func GinMiddleware(allowOrigin string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowOrigin)
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Content-Length, X-CSRF-Token, Token, session, Origin, Host, Connection, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, X-Requested-With")

        if c.Request.Method == http.MethodOptions {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }

        c.Request.Header.Del("Origin")

        c.Next()
    }
}

func main() {
    router := gin.New()

    server := socketio.NewServer(nil)

    server.OnConnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn) error {
        s.SetContext("")
        log.Println("connected:", s.ID())
        s.Emit("reply", "hello world")
        return nil
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "notice", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        log.Println("notice:", msg)
        s.Emit("reply", "have "+msg)
    })

    server.OnEvent("/chat", "msg", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) string {
        s.SetContext(msg)
        return "recv " + msg
    })

    server.OnEvent("/", "bye", func(s socketio.Conn) string {
        last := s.Context().(string)
        s.Emit("bye", last)
        s.Close()
        return last
    })

    server.OnError("/", func(s socketio.Conn, e error) {
        log.Println("meet error:", e)
    })

    server.OnDisconnect("/", func(s socketio.Conn, msg string) {
        log.Println("closed", msg)
        log.Println("why????")
    })

    go func() {
        if err := server.Serve(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("socketio listen error: %s\n", err)
        }
    }()
    defer server.Close()

    router.Use(GinMiddleware("*"))
    router.GET("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    router.POST("/socket.io/*any", gin.WrapH(server))
    router.StaticFS("/public", http.Dir("../asset"))

    if err := router.Run(":8000"); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed run app: ", err)
    }
}
```

and I write a html with js as client :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Go WebSocket Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello World2</h2>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.0/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
            var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000/socket.io/",{ transports: ["websocket"], pingInterval: 60000  });  

           socket.on('news', function (data) {
               console.log(data.hello);
                socket.emit('my new event', { my:'new data' });/
            });  
            socket.on('other', function (data) {
                console.log(data.hello);  
                socket.emit('event1', { my:'other data' });  
            }); 
            socket.on("connect_error", (error) => {
                // ...
                console.log("err:", error)
            });
            socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
                if (reason === "io server disconnect") {
                    // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
                    // socket.connect();
                }
                // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
                console.log("reason:", reason)
            });
            socket.emit("notice", "my_notice")
        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I get repeated reconnection. From devtools, it seems connect to server, and then close connection, and keep this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally find the cause. Though documentation of `go-socket.io` say it support socket.io protocol v1.4, it's not compatible with socket.io.js v1.4.0. I change js lib version to socket.io.js v1.3.0 and everything works as expected.

It's really a pity that go-socket.io still lack support for socket.io protocol v2/v3/v4